# Angular 9 IVY Lazy loaded component bindings not working

Tags: angular, angular-ivy

Directives such as `ngIf`, `ngClass`, `ngStyle` don't work in lazy loaded component (introduced in Angular 9).

`core.js:12626 Can't bind to 'xxx' since it isn't a known property of 'xxx'.`

The only binding I managed to get it working is something like: `[style.color]="color"`.
Lazy loading the webpack js bundle works fine as long as there is no binding or there is just simple binding as `[style.color]="color"`.

The Lazy loaded component is not declared in NgModule and it is loaded as such

```
 async lazy1() {
    this.viewContainerRef.clear();
    const { LazyComponent } = await import("./lazy.component");
    this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(
      this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(LazyComponent)
    );
  }
```

Full example (can't be run in stackblitz for some reason): 
    https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zyp3wm

This can e reproduced in a step by step fashion by following the article below
https://johnpapa.net/angular-9-lazy-loading-components/
You just need to add a `ngIf` somewhere in a one of the lazy component to get the problem I am experiencing.

Comment: This is expected behavior according to angular team. One should wrap the component in a module and load the module instead. More info: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/36604

Answer (score 0):

Rendering a component which not declared in any NgModule or to be exact that using other elements that not declared or import in the same NgModule is not possible.

I wrote a blog post on the future of standalone components in the world of Angular Ivy a few months ago - you can find it [here](https://blog.angularindepth.com/the-future-of-standalone-components-in-the-post-ivy-release-days-e7ed9b9b4dcd).
It might help you understand the optional NgModule perspective, and what are the costs (Manual CD, different injector etc...)